# Что программисту нужно знать в Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, работа

Часто в вакансиях есть такие требования, как базовые или уверенные знания Linux.
По вашему опыту, что именно требуется работодателю от программиста в этой теме?

Comment: Для начала, чтобы командная строка не вызывала удивление. Умение поставить систему в текстовом режиме в минимальной конфигурации, а потом расширить до требуемой. Суммируя, поставьте себе и настройте Arch Linux без чужой помощи и интернета, вот это в 90% случаев будет достаточной проверкой ваших знаний системы GNU/Linux.

Comment: просто не падай в ступор когда нужно сделать `./configure&&make` - за базу сойдеет)

Comment: @eri — это никакого отношения к работе в ОС GNU/Linux не имеет.

Comment: @0andriy но добраться до места применнения этих команд ещё надо.) а вот там через гну.

Comment: @0andriy умение ставить систему - это действительно те знания, которые требуются от программиста?

Comment: А кто по-вашему будет её вам ставить на ваше рабочее место? Ну да ладно, а если чего-то сломается, кого вы звать будете? Маму? Папу?

Comment: 0andriy, в идеале конечно админа. Но у меня был вопрос о повседневных умениях программиста.